# Database design for multiple objects with similar attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following objects and respective attributes in my unity3d game:

1. **Lumbermill**

   - Level
   - Production
   - MaxCap
   - StoneUpPrice
   - ClayUpPrice
2. **Quarry**

   - Level
   - Production
   - MaxCap
   - ClayUpPrice
   - WoodUpPrice
3. **Claypit**

   - Level
   - Production
   - MaxCap
   - WoodUpPrice
   - StoneUpPrice

My question is, how should I organize this on my Mysql database?

I thought already of:

- making a unique table named Buildings and placing all attributes as a column, also with a user_id that refers to the respective user
- making a table for each Building with the respective attributes, all of them with a user_id too.

I didn't learn about database in my college yet, so I would really appreciate any help. My English is not one of the best, but I tried to make myself as clear as possible.

Thanks for now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make 2 tables

1. Category: To hold the categories like Lumbermill, Quarry etc
2. objects : with category_id as foreign key

Category

```
id
name
```

objects

```
category_id
Level
Production
MaxCap
StoneUpPrice(can be null for non relevant category)
ClayUpPrice(can be null for non relevant category)
WoodUpprice(can be null for non relevant category)
```

EDIT prior to your comment

You can make seperate bridge table like player_object like below

player_object

```
player_id
object_id
```

Assuming you have players table like below

players

```
id
name
```

Comment: And how would the player know that this object belong to him? Because the stoneUpPrice gets higher when a player upgrades it. So each player would need a object